# Вопрос с телеграм ботом на питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Главный вопрос - как сделать отправку сообщений ассинхронными.

```
    elif str(message.text).isdigit():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Группы", reply_markup=now_person.get_groups_of_facult(message.text))
```

Когда к боту приходит много сообщений он начинает работать медленно
Пытался добавить к функции async и к отправке await вот так

```
    elif str(message.text).isdigit():
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Группы", reply_markup= await now_person.get_groups_of_facult(message.text))
```

Но при запуске этого блока ловлю ошибку. Использую pyTelegramBotApi

Comment: Перейти на aiogram

Comment: А по другому никак?